# Theorem 6.1.1. of Durrett - Proof that $X_n$ is a Markov chain given a probability measure induced on sequence space.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I have difficulty following the proof of Theorem 6.1.1. from Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples.

Before proceeding to the theorem, below are the definitions used in the text.

[image]

[image]

Now follows the proof. I don't understand the paragraph starting "To do this,...". How do we set $f$ as an indicator function to replace $p(x_n,B_n)$ when $p$ depends on two variables and the ps in the integral are of the form $p(x_{n-1},dx_n)$? I'm very confused about this part. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we set $f$ as an indicator function to replace $p(x_n,B_n)$ when $p$ depends on two variables and the ps in the integral are of the form $p(x_{n-1},dx_n)$?

- We are only replacing $p(x_n, B_{n+1})$ by $f(x_n)$. (There is a small typo.) We are *not* replacing the $p(x_i,dx_{i+1})$.
- $B_{n+1}$ is fixed, so we are thinking of the function $x_n \mapsto p(x_n,B_{n+1})$ generally as some function $f(x_n)$.

---

Demonstration for a characteristic function: essentially uses (6.1.1).
\begin{align}
&\int_{B_0} \mu(dx) \int_{B_1} p(x_0,dx_1) \cdots \int_{B_n} p(x_{n-1}, dx_n) 1_{(x_n \in C)}\\
&= \int_{B_0} \mu(dx) \int_{B_1} p(x_0,dx_1) \cdots \int_{B_n \cap C} p(x_{n-1}, dx_n)\\
&= P_\mu(X_0\in B_0,\ldots, X_{n-1} \in B_{n-1}, X_n \in B_n \cap C)\\
&= P_\mu(A \cap \{X_n \in C\})\\
&=\int_A 1_{(X_n \in C)} \mathop{dP_\mu}
\end{align}

Comment: But then how do we get the equality of the two expressions? Can you show this specifically, for say, $f=\Chi_C$, just any characteristic function? I think in this case, the bottom expression should be $P_\mu (A\cap \{X_n\in C\})$ but I don't know how the other expression becomes the same as this.